# AsyncTask and jsoup doesn't return anything

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

For some reason, my code isn't working. I've set the proper permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, but I'm not getting any results. I'm pretty new to both `jsoup` and `AsyncTask`, so I am probably doing something wrong. Does anyone have any idea to what is going on here?

```
  public class Stuff extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        TextView tv;
        String text = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Document document;
            try {
                document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla").timeout(10000).get();

                Elements elements = document.select("a#gb_2");
                if (elements.size() > 0) {
                    text = elements.get(0).text();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                text = "Error:" + e;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return text;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv.setText(text);

        }
    }
```

Comment: @Ahmad I'm stupid, Ignore the question xD. Do you wanna answer it the question?

Comment: So you weren't executing it correctly?

Comment: Forgot `new Stuff().execute();` xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to execute `Stuff()`. Oops.